# On Android 10, how to trigger a pop-up system message for WLAN ON and OFF permission?

Tags: android, user-controls, android-10.0

Android 10 doesn't allow app to turn WLAN on/off any more. (see this FYR: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/128554616)

But I need a way to get around this restrictions. By searching around, I saw an app that did the best effort so far to allow the user easily choose whether one wants to enable/disable WLAN. Please see the screenshot below.

[image: System Pop-up Message for WLAN On/Off]

Does anyone has any idea how this pop-up message can be triggered? Is a workaround available?

Comment: Android 10 now requires you to use [settings panels](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/features#settings-panels) in order to turn on/off Wi-Fi.

Comment: Thanks Edric, I have tried this already. Doing this means the user would have to, in the Pop-up Settings Panel, turn off the WLAN then on again, which is really annoying to users. What's smart about the mechanism in attached screenshot is that it asks for WLAN On/Off Permission from the user. Once the user agrees, or wait out until the pop-up times out (equivalent to user's manual Allow), then app can proceed with next step. Do you have any idea on how to invoke this WLAN On/Off Permission pop-up?

Comment: At least it's better than having to navigate to the Settings app to turn on/off Wi-Fi, where the user might not return back to your app - this is why this feature was introduced such that the user does not have to navigate to the Settings app to change the phone's settings. (P.S. My name's _Edric_, not Eric.)

Comment: Sorry Edric, for the wrong name. Apologies! Also, I accidentally posted it before I was able to finish editing. Please let me know again. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, for replying late. But this answer could help someone. The app on which you are able to see the popup message has probably built using **TargetSdk** as **28**. This is just a workaround. Anyhow when you upgrade your app to Android 10, you will surely update the **TargetSdk** as **29** and this popup won't be triggering at all.